# AngularJs - Send data in ng-click to validate email

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to check if the inserted email is in a valid format so I can choose what to do next. I'm trying to achieve this by sending `myForm.$valid` value inside the function that runs when the user hits the button to submit the email.

Here is how I'm trying to achieve it.

**HTML**

```
<input type="email" required="true" name="email-input" placeholder="Input Email">
<button type="button" ng-click="toggle(email-input.$valid)">Request</button>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('showHide',function($scope){
        $scope.toggle = function(valid) {
            alert(valid);
        };
    });
```

The value `valid` i get is always "0". Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you shouldn't use a dash `-` in your name. this messes something up in angular. try it without the `-` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I noticed the dash was causing an error but changing it didn't fix the error. I was missing "ng-model" in the input. Somehow it is required to be able to access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to surround your input with a form.

```
<div ng-form name="myForm">
<input type="email" required="true" name="email-input" placeholder="Input Email">
<button type="button" ng-click="toggle(myForm.email-input.$valid)">Request</button>
```

And this way, it's also accessible from your controller directly :

```
app.controller('showHide',function($scope){
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        if(!$scope.myForm.email-input.$valid){
            alert(valid);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work out. Instead of a "0" i get "undefined" printed now.  I also changed the name "email-input" to just "email" because i was getting an error due to the "-".

Comment: ng-model is required for validation. Try addind ng-model="email" to your <input />

Comment: Thanks ! `ng-model="email"` did the trick ! I miss that in the documentation. Here is the link if anyone has the same problem: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel